# Can't use ExtentedProperties for google calendar API

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I have some trouble trying to update a Google Agenda event which already exists. I would like to set an ExtendedProperties but this field is always set to NULL.

```
    $event = $service->events->get($calendarId, $eventId);
    $extendedProperties = New EventExtendedProperties();
    $extendedProperties->setPrivate('blalblabla');
    $event->setExtendedProperties($extendedProperties);
    $updatedEvent = $service->events->update($calendarId, $event->getId(), $event);
```

What can I do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

instead of providing string `'blalblabla'`, you should provide an associative array like `array('foo'=>'bar')` 

Your code should look like this:

```
$event = $service->events->get($calendarId, $eventId);
$extendedProperties = New EventExtendedProperties();
$extendedProperties->setPrivate(array('custom'=>'blalblabla'));
$event->setExtendedProperties($extendedProperties);
$updatedEvent = $service->events->update($calendarId, $event->getId(), $event);
```

I hope this helps!